# How can I read multiple (variable length) arguments from user input and store in variables and pass it to functions

Tags: python, split, user-input

Trying to create a calculator, which can take variable length of integers separated by space. I am able to create a basic calculator that would read two args and do operations. Below is what I am trying to achieve.

```
select operation: Add
Enter nos: 1 65 12 (this length can increase and any variable lenght of integers can be given)
```

I am not sure how would I pass this variable length of int to functions, suppose addition function. I can do it for two variables.

Adding what I am aware of:

```
x = input("enter operation to perform")
a = input("1st no.")
b = input("2nd no.")
def add(a,b):
    return a+b
if x == 1:
    print add(a,b)
```

Not sure how can I pass multiple args read from input to function.

Comment: Use sys module `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: @ArpitSolanki That's not what he wants. He simply wants user input. That can be achieved using `input()`.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki: how can i pass that to function?

Comment: @ChristianDean: yes using input(), which will have variable length of args, and then those to be passed to functions and so that a math operation be performed on those int.

Comment: I've edited my original answer to show how the input can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using input you can achieve this:

```
>>> result = input("enter your numbers ")
enter your numbers 4 5
>>> result
'4 5'
>>> a, b = result.split()
>>> a
'4'
>>> b
'5'
>>> int(a) + int(b)
9
```

The `split` method will split your string by default on space and create a list of those items.

Now, if you had something more complicated like:

```
>>> result = input("enter your numbers ")
enter your numbers 4 5 6 7 8 3 4 5
>>> result
'4 5 6 7 8 3 4 5'
>>> numbers = result.split()
>>> numbers
['4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '3', '4', '5']
>>> numbers = list(map(int, numbers))
>>> numbers
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5]
>>> def add(numbers):
...  return sum(numbers)
...
>>> add(numbers)
42
```

As you can see you are taking a longer sequence of numbers split by space. When you call `split` on it, you will see you have a list of numbers but represented as strings. You need to have integers. So, this is where the call to `map` comes in to type the strings to integers. Since map returns a map object, we need a list (hence call to list around the map). Now we have a list of integers, and our newly created `add` function takes a list of numbers, and we simply call `sum` on it.

If we wanted something that required a little more work, like subtraction, as suggested. Let us assume we already have our list of numbers, to make the example smaller to look at:

Furthermore, to help make it more readable I will do it step by step:

```
>>> def sub(numbers):
...  res = 0
...  for n in numbers:
...   res -= n
...  return res
...
>>> sub([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
-28
```

Comment: how can this variables(which would be of any length) read and split be passed to functions !!!

Comment: @shivrk You don't need those extra exclamation marks. Being frustrated is not a correct approach here. You are getting people to answer your questions. Getting *angry* is not appreciated.

Comment: @shivrk you are already passing a and b to your function `add`: `if x == 1: print add(a,b)`. I do not understand what you do not understand.

Comment: @AGNGazer The question states that they are trying to figure out how to do it for a variable amount of inputs. So, if they enter "1 2 3 4 5", taking just a and b won't work. So, the answer here is to either pass an entire list, or unpack it through an arbitrary list of arguments with `*` as indicated in another answer.

Comment: @idjaw: Thank u for replying,Trying out your answer. didn't realize that xtra xclamation could mean that, will be careful replying onwards now.

Comment: @shivrk No worries. :)

Comment: I think both you and Rosh cheated a bit here :-) Implementing an `add()` function is easy. `sum()` does the work for you. I think you should show how something like subtraction would be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you use *args it can take an arbitrary amount of positional arguments. You can make similar procedures for other operations.

```
def addition(*args):
    return sum(args)

calc = {
        '+':addition,
        #'-':subtraction,
        #'/':division,
        #'*':multiplication,
        }

def get_input():
    print('Please enter numbers with a space seperation...')
    values = input()
    listOfValues = [int(x) for x in values.split()]
    return listOfValues


val_list = get_input()

print(calc['+'](*val_list))
```

This is the way I would implement the calculator. Have a dictionary that holds the operations (I would use lambdas), then you can pass the list of numbers to the specific operation in the dictionary.